# Xamarin Forms Working with Fonts

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to reproduce this sample
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithFonts

Especially these lines of code:

```
var labelBoldItalic = new Label {
    Text = "BoldItalic",
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize (14, FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
};
```

**But VS 2013 says: The Name FontAttributes does not exist in the current context.**
[image]

Xamarin Version:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the most recent Xamarin.Forms package?

Comment: I think so, It's strange because I've downloaded the sample that I mentioned above and version is Xamarin.Forms.1.2.3.6257. But when I create a new solution the version is: Xamarin.Forms.1.0.6186.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you **Jason**.

I solved via NUGET:

> Get-Project -all | Install-Package Xamarin.Forms